# Intellisense JSDoc for Mixins and/or Factory Functions

Tags: intellisense, mixins, factory-pattern, jsdoc

## My Problem

I'm currently using Visual Code Studio, the lastest version. I'm trying to get the intellisense to show up for the methods on the instance created by a factory function. The methods are going to be applied via object composition (so added directly as properties on the object).

so the function that acts as a constructore basically returns:

```js
function makeWrappedObj() {
  var obj = { /* random data */ }; // Then add methods to obj
  Object.keys(methods).forEach(key => a[key] = methods[key]; );
  return obj;
}
var methods = {
  /**
   * Yay documentation
   * @returns {Object}
   */
  method1: function() { return null; }
};
var instance = makeWrappedObj();
instance.method1( // What documentation to show up here
instance. // and here
```

Is the basic idea. [Here](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/1244)'s someone doing something similar. I'll address that in the third possible solution.

## Solutions I've tried

**1)** @class on makeWrappedObj I think only works if you attach methods on to makeWrappedObj.prototype which is not what I'm doing so that doesn't work. Unless I'm misunderstanding something.

**2)** @namespace solution

```js
/* @namespace ClassName */

/* @returns {ClassName}
function createWrappedObj() {
  var obj = { /* random data */ }; // Then add methods to obj
  Object.keys(methods).forEach(key => a[key] = methods[key]; );
  return obj;
}

var methods = {
/**
 * Currently the soultion I'm using
 * @memberof ClassName
 * @param {number} a
 **/
  method1: function (a)  {}
};
var instance = makeWrapperObj();
instance.method1( // Only shows documentation here
```

So this sort of works. The two problems are that:

- methods on instances only get documentation when you type out the full `instance.method(` and not in the `instance.` case--not really a big deal
- if you have a method name that is the same as an in-built function, eg. toString, `instance.toString(` will block any documentation you have from showing and show the native toString default documentation instaed.

**3)** @typedef like the link above.

```js
/** Can be placed anywhere
 * @typedef {ClassName}
 * @property {function} method1
 * dunno how to document arguments with this method
 * but it gets the intellisense menu to pop up for "instance." after dot
 */

/* @returns {ClassName} */
function createdWrappedObject() {
  var obj = { /* random data */ }; // Then add methods to obj
  Object.keys(methods).forEach(key => a[key] = methods[key]; );
  return obj;
}
    
var methods = {
  method1: function (a)  {}
};
var instance = makeWrappedObj();
instance. // Yay
instance.method1( // Doesn't work
```

Has the benefit of showing up when one types `instance.` however has a few disadvantages

- Do not know how to specify arguments passed to method1. Maybe it's not possible.
- @typedef requires all documentations to be specified in its own comment block. So I have to be redundant between specific documentation on the methods and the typedef
- loses the docummentation once you write out the entire method up until the open paren. Sort of workable...

Note: I am willing to just assign all the methods manually one by one instead of doing a foreach on all the keys of the methods mixin.

Also I do not know how to specify the parameters for a function passed as a. This should be possible since `Array.map(` specifies three arguments for its function call.

The goal is to get documentation when someone imports this as a library with require, or just includes it as a library in browser side script.

Comment: Well I may have found an [answer](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7515). In other words it's not possible as of yet, unless there's something clever.

Comment: Also I'd like to add that map, filter, reduce all already implement this feature, though how to replicate it is beyond me.